# Excluding specific files in the email attachment on automated emails from Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Im running an automated build on jenkins that sends automated emails with attachments using the ext email plugin. I am able to extract the required attachments from the folder but need to exclude one specific file. How do i achieve that?
I need to exclude the 'index.html' file but get the other html files in the folder

I am currently getting all html files in the email that is sent out without excluding the 'index.html' file

Ive tried the following -

```
<fileset dir="**/target/surefire-reports" casesensitive="yes">   
<include name="/*.html"/>   
<exclude name="/index.html"/> </fileset>

<delete file="**/target/surefire-reports/index.html"/>, 
**/target/surefire-reports/*.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Jenkins **Ext Email Plugin** doesn't support excluding syntax, only including.

From help:

> The format is a comma separated list of Ant include file syntax.

So you need to try find most suitable including patterns (or list all needed files). For example, if all files have at least 6 symbols in name, try something like

```
**/target/surefire-reports/??????*.html
```

Comment: well, one of the files is dynamic in the nature. So im not able to provide a specific file name. But will try more suitable include patterns.

Comment: If all files have the name with more than 5 symbols, I propose you to add something like `??????*.html` to match files with at least 6 symbols name (updated in the answer).

Comment: i tried what you suggested and tried to target a specific file using the below expression - 

**/target/surefire-reports/H*.html 

Neither seems to work, it just extracts all html files from the folder

Comment: Did you tried that in freestyle job `Post-build Actions -> Editable email notification -> Attachments` ? Or you're using Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: its a freestyle job. I am thinking the only other way maybe to copy the two files I need to another folder within the workspace possibly and then extract the files from there

Comment: Ok, so, are you trying to include files using some tags like `<fileset dir ...>`? Because you don't need to do that for `Editable email notification -> Attachments`, you need just specify parameters like `*/target/surefire-reports/H.html` and that's all.